# uncaught typeError when using destructuring in arguments

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

I have this function code that I am using to create a code snippet in javascript. I want to know if I can make it look better since I think this code I did is not looking professionally well.

I tried using destructuring but for some reason, my browser show me this message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

I would like to know if there is any better way of passing multiple parameters to a function in javascript sending the arguments as an object literal? And Why does it say that the string contains an invalid character?

Many thanks.

```js
const create = function ({t, v, p}) {
        let n = document.createElement(t);
        n.innerHTML = v;
        p.appendChild(n);
        return n;
    };
    // create the list for reference
    let ul = create({
        t: 'ul',
        v: null,
        p: document.body
    });
```

Here is the full JS code.

```js
const createsnippets = function (e) {
    // the reference node -- we atually have one ID for headlines 
    let headlines = document.getElementById('headlines');
    // utility function to add new HTML DOM element 


    const create = function ({t, v, p}) {
        let n = document.createElement(t);
        n.innerHTML = v;
        p.appendChild(n);
        return n;
    };
    // create the list for reference
    let ul = create({
        t: 'ul',
        v: null,
        p: document.body
    });

    // find all newsarticle classess and add then to snippet in sequence
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.newsarticle > h4')).forEach(function (h4) {
        create('li', h4.textContent + ' ... ' + h4.nextElementSibling.innerText, ul);
    });

    // insertion re-factors HTMl to ensure the layout (markup and CSS) when displaed
    headlines.parentNode.insertBefore(ul, headlines.nextSibling)
}

// once prepared, we can display the loaded content as snippet/collection 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createsnippets);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter destructuring is fine, but you're calling `create` in two different ways. This call is fine:

```
let ul = create({
  t: 'ul',
  v: null,
  p: document.body
});
```

...but this one is not:

```
create('li', h4.textContent + ' ... ' + h4.nextElementSibling.innerText, ul);
```

This will cause your create function to try to destructure a `t`, `v`, and `p` property *from the string `'li'`*. The destructuring code translates roughly to this, and here's what would happen with that second call:

```
function(param) {                          // param = 'li'
  let t = param.t;                         // t = 'li'.t -> t = undefined
  let v = param.v;                         // v = 'li'.v -> v = undefined
  let p = param.p;                         // p = 'li'.p -> p = undefined
  let n = document.createElement(t);       // n = document.createElement(undefined)
  n.innerHTML = v;                         
  p.appendChild(n);                        // undefined.appendChild(n)
  return n;
}
```

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
create({
  t: 'li', 
  v: `${h4.textContent} ... ${h4.nextElementSibling.innerText}`,
  p: ul
});
```

Comment: I see, this is exactly what's happening is getting undefined. but if I remove the `create('li', h4.textContent + ' ... ' + h4.nextElementSibling.innerText, ul);` how can i display the snippet.

Comment: @user12700367: see my last snippet of code. That's what you'll replace your incorrect call with.

Comment: I did but I get the message can't find the variable h4

Comment: I would like to share with you my full code. link https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/yqoxcLfb/41/   I really really appreciate your help

Comment: The `h4` variable is inside of your `forEach` loops; the replaced `create` function would still have to be inside that loop.

Comment: something like this `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.newsarticle > h4')).forEach(function (h4) {
        create();
    });`

Comment: No, that's passing _no_ parameters into the `create` function... `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.newsarticle > h4')).forEach(function (h4) { create({
  t: 'li', 
  v: h4.textContent + ' ... ' + h4.nextElementSibling.innerText,
  p: ul
}); });`

Comment: that's weird.. the message still saying can't find the variable h4